# json_encode character issue

Tags: php, json

I'm having a strange issue with json_encode.

Doing this:

```
echo json_encode(array('action' => 'act'));
```

Returns this:

```
"\u0000\"action\":\"act\"}
```

Yes, without starting bracket. How to solve this?

Comment: This works fine for me, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://codepad.org/e80qDBBC

Comment: This definitely has to be a problem with your PHP installation/server configuration etc. Code works fine for me, too. Have you tried running the PHP file from the command line? Does it behave the same way?

Comment: It's working fine on my server with PHP 5.3. i'm trying now on a free hosting, it has 5.4, i have the problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that json_encode was running twice.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't This Problem Output is

```
 {"action":"act"}
```

Comment: Yes, everybody knows that it should return that, if it would, i would not have this problem.

Comment: @wintercounter are you test it with some other code like page compressor? may by run with htaccess